# Converting and array of objects to a model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After fetching JSON and parsing and pushing it to an array, I have:

```
[object, object]
```

I would like to convert each object to the following data model:

```
import { ItemModel } from './item.model'; 

export class TodolistModel {
    name: string;
    items: Array<ItemModel> = []; 
}
```

I have attempted this:

```
parsedTodolists.forEach(parsedTodolist => {
      let loadChecklist = Object.assign(new TodolistModel(), parsedTodolist); }
```

But this leads to a funky assignment:

```
TodolistModel {0: Object, 1: Object, items: Array(0)}
```

I am trying to achieve this:

```
[TodolistModel, TodolistModel]
```

Thank you!

Comment: It seems your `parsedTodolist` is an array. Do a `console.log(parsedTodolist)` to see what we have.

Comment: @Diulei that's correct it is. What are you thinking?

Comment: if you want to put this `parsedTodolist` as a `items` property on `TodolistModel` object, you need to use:  `let loadChecklist = Object.assign(new TodolistModel(), {items: parsedTodolist});` But, in this case I dont know what value you need to put on `name`. If each item on `parsedTodolist` needs to be an `TodolistModel` you need to do another foreach. I dont have enough information about your logic to give a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data I was fetching was saved as the model. Therefore I don't need to "convert" my data back to the model. It already adheres to the model parameters.

E.g.

```
[TodolistModel, TodolistModel]
```

Was saved to a DB. I pulled it, JSON parsed it and had:

```
[Object, Object]
```

Then I pushed it into an array and saw:

```
[Array (2)]
```

I shouldn't have pushed it to an array since it's already an array. I needed to iterate and push each object to my array.

I was mistaken it two areas: 1.) It already adheres to the model, and 2.) JSON.parse creates an array!

Hope this helps someome :)